# How to get a Worker Thread return data in c# [Base on .Net framework 4.0]

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I already knew some tech bring in .Net Framework 4.5 for Asynchronous task.It's can make me out of the Thread.Just like Below demo:
```

```
//The main idea is I use async task to make my program not be blocked

//In main function:
 var task = new TaskDemo();
 task.AsyncPrintString();

//TaskDemo Class
public void AsyncPrintString()
{
    Task<string> Hello = AsyncGetString();
    string World = SyncGetString();
    Console.WriteLine(Hello.Result +  World);
}
private async Task<string> AsyncGetString()
{
    return await TaskGetString();
}
private Task<string> TaskGetString()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "Hello";
    });
}
private string SyncGetString()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return "Hello";
}
//With Task<string> I can get the string returned by asynchronous execution
```

```

Now I got a problem in some specific factor( my legacy program is base on .net 4.0). So I plan to create a worker thread directly to handle asynchronous tasks to achieve the same logic, like below
```

```
private string WorkThreadGetString()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return "Hello";
}

Thread t = new Thread(/*ThreadStart*/ WorkThreadGetString);
t.Start();
/****This is what I supported ********
var result = t.Start();
*************************************/
//but ThreadStart require nothing to return
```

```

What should I do? Is there something else I can deal with this?

Comment: Unrelated, but please do not use `Thread.Sleep` in async methods. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28314695

Comment: Just use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Comment: First of all thanks, it's just a demo. I use to indicateing AsyncGetString() is a Async method need used long time to execute

Comment: @SirRufo  Are there Threads in C# can do the same thing but I don't know?

Comment: You can use async/await and Tasks with .net 4.0 / VisualStudio >= 2012